# How to get pynput code to work under Wayland (and Windows, too)?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, pynput, wayland

I have a trivial example program that works on Windows and from within PyCharm (on Linux, on a Wayland display):

```
from pynput import keyboard
from queue import Queue

kbd_q = Queue(maxsize=1)

def on_activate_s(): 
    kbd_q.put("Hotkey s")


listener = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
    's': on_activate_s,
})
listener.start()

while True:
    key = kbd_q.get()
    if key:
        print(key)
```

It does not receive any keyboard events when running in the terminal under Wayland (Linux). [Here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html#linux) are the limitations of pynput under Linux. I want to control my program with Hotkeys (several keys pressed at once), that is why I would like to use pynput or even pypi keyboard. But if I understand correctly, Wayland purposefully prevents direct access to the keyboard.

How can I get my code to run under Linux and Windows with as little workaround as possible?

My ideas:

- Run as `root` - not great. My program will create files, which can be awkward with wrong file permissions and more permissions than strictly necessary. Also, when running with `sudo,` it fails to detect the X server.
- turn my application into an X client. Is that possible without the considerable overhead? How does that impact the portability to Windows? Would it make sense to quickly turn this into a pyQT app?

Is there an easy solution for this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This works both on Linux and Windows, from within PyCharm and from within a terminal. I am sure there is a lot of unused functionality in PyQt, like this. It hurts me to write code like this because I prefer them lean and simple. Suggestions to that end are welcome.

```
import queue
import sys
from pynput import keyboard
from queue import Queue
import datetime

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()
w.resize(300,300)
w.setWindowTitle("Keyboard Events")
w.show()

kbd_q = Queue(maxsize=1)

def on_activate_1a(): kbd_q.put("Hotkey 1a")
def on_activate_2s(): kbd_q.put("Hotkey 2s")
def on_activate_s(): kbd_q.put("Hotkey s")


listener = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
    '1+a': on_activate_1a,
    '2+s': on_activate_2s,
    's': on_activate_s,
})
listener.start()
listener.wait()

ten_sec = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
while datetime.datetime.now() < ten_sec:
    print(".")
    try:
        key = kbd_q.get(True, timeout=0.1)
        if key:
            print(key)
    except queue.Empty:
        pass


listener.stop()
print("10 sec passed")
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```